# GIMP: How to hide all parts of an image that are not covered by a shape?

Tags: gimp, mask

I have two layers, A (a fancy shape) and B (an image). I want all the parts of B that are covered by A to be visible, and all the parts of B that are not covered by A to not be visible. Put another way, I want to use A to make a cut-out of B. Is there a way to do this?

I have been trying to use an inverted mask, but for some reason it makes the remaining part of the image partly transparent.

Comment: Hi. Can you please show what you are trying to do or what has failed?  It's hard to answer questions like this without seeing something. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shape to create a mask and then use this mask to be applied to your other layer.

Answer (score 2):

Set your shape **under** the image layer, and set the "Composite mode" of the image layer to `Composite mode: Clip to background`. If you have more layers, use a group for the two to limit the scope of the `Clip to background` to the layers that are in the group.

[image]

- You can also set the `Composite mode` directly in the right-click menu of the layer.
- You can use multiple layers for the shape.